# owin Identity in visual studio 2013

Tags: identity, owin

```
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

im using vs2013 and this line of code isnt working

it says

> Error 1   'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext' and no extension method 'GetOwinContext' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The `AuthenticationManager` class resolves to `System.Net` namespace

Comment: Have you added the reference to the relevant assembly?

Comment: thanks, missed this assembly Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Answer (score 7):

I just created an entire tutorial on adding this from Visual Studio 2012 at httpJunkie.com But yes, You need Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb and it can be found at NuGet.Org

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/2.0.2

Or installed via package Manager Console:

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb